# Count how many queries were executed on a page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Is there a simple way to count all the queries executed on a CakePHP page?

I will just need a number, representing how many queries were executed from my AppController start, to the end of the page render.

Comment: Are you looking for just the information or a count variable in a controller?

Comment: See edited post.  It will be a number for how many queries my code executed.

Comment: Are you not using [debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)?

Comment: @AD7six No, but thanks for the link.  I need the number of queries to be displayed regardless of the app debug config value.  Users on the production version of the app should see the number too.

Comment: take a look at the [sql_dump.ctp element](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Elements/sql_dump.ctp). This is what Cake uses to output a list of all queries performed (I don't know if it takes updates in to consideration). You might be able to use some of the functionality.

Comment: @BadHorsie unless you're building phpmyadmin in a cake app, that sounds like a bad idea. If you have enough queries to want to know how many queries are issued, there's something wrong with your app. You need to turn fullDebug on (a property on the datasource object) for it to log queries at all; or to specify `log => true` in all queries.

Comment: @AD7six, so regardless of what the solution is or my reasons for wanting it, it's not possible without debug = 2 anyway?

Comment: @BadHorsie no - that's not what I've said

Comment: @AD7six You know I'm not going to add `'log' => true` to every query, so my question still stands.  This isn't possible unless debug = 2? Or do you have a solution?

Comment: @BadHorsie if you explain why you want to do this - I'll write an answer; I'm not going to go out of my way to help you do something that I think is wrong - even though I've already said what you need to do "You need to turn fullDebug on (a property on the datasource object)".

Comment: @AD7siz Probably not necessary to be so hostile and condescending, my dear. This is a forum for helping each other, not patronising people who you think are below your standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically an edit of the sql_dump element. Which resides in lib/cake/view/elements.
It is a starting point for you anyway.

```
$sources = ConnectionManager::sourceList();
$logs = array();
foreach ($sources as $source):
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($source);
    if (!method_exists($db, 'getLog')):
        continue;
    endif;
    $logs[$source] = $db->getLog();
endforeach;

$queries = 0;
foreach ($logs as $source => $logInfo):
    $queries += $logInfo['count'];
endforeach;
```

Comment: That's going to always return 0 (without further changes) unless debug is set to 2 - as that's the only time queries are logged at all.

Comment: Is there any reason this line is present in the sql_dump.ctp file if it's always going to return 0? if (!class_exists('ConnectionManager') || Configure::read('debug') < 2) {

Comment: because "do as little as possible" is a good idea, and  `Configure::read('debug')` is not a constant. If there have been no models loaded at all (the ConnectionManager class isn't loaded) or when the element is rendered, debug is less than 2 (nothing of the element is required at all) - bail.